# Пронумеровать найденные совпадения

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

открываю файл в цикле и построчно прохожусь по нему заменяя регулярными выражениями необходимый текст

```
for i in f:
 line = re.sub(r'#.{1,}?#', r'<>\g<0></>', line )
```

Как можно сделать, что бы следующий найденный элемент заменялся числом на 1 больше?
т.е. примерно так:

```
line = re.sub(r'#.{1,}?#', r'<1>\g<0></1>', line )
line = re.sub(r'#.{1,}?#', r'<2>\g<0></2>', line )
line = re.sub(r'#.{1,}?#', r'<3>\g<0></3>', line )
```

как я понимаю каждый раз когда находится совпадение нужно добавлять в переменную +1 но как написать такую проверку мне не совсем понимаю

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

Что-то про [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) все забыли:

```py
for idx, line in enumerate(f):
    line = re.sub(r'#.+?#', rf'<{idx}>\g<0></{idx}>', line)
```

В Вашей регулярке заменил `{1,}` на `+`, т.к. это одно и то же.

Но, как отметил [insolor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1365), Ваш подход не совсем верен, если задача: *"что бы следующий найденный элемент заменялся числом на 1 больше"*, т.к. при Вашем подходе у элементов будет тег не таким, каким по счёту нашелся элемент, а таким, **в какой по счёту строке** он нашёлся.

---

Если же решать задачу *"что бы следующий найденный элемент заменялся числом на 1 больше"*, то предлагаю такой вариант:

```py
class CounterReplacer:
    def __init__(self, start=0, step=1):
        self._counter = start
        self._step = step

    def replace(self, match: re.Match):
        i = self._counter
        self._counter += self._step
        return f'<{i}>{match[0]}</{i}>'


# ...

replacer = CounterReplacer(start=1)
for line in f:
    line = re.sub(r'#.+?#', replacer.replace, line)
```

Comment: Скорее всего нужно будет еще в re.sub добавить параметр `count=1`, чтобы каждый раз заменялось только одно вхождение, иначе после первой итерации все сразу заменится, а следующие итерации будут работать вхолостую.

Comment: @insolor Спасибо, дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 4):

В начале совет: не используйте `{1,}`, это "длинная версия" квантификатора `+`. Чтобы захватить пустые строки между двух `#` не используйте `.+?`, используйте `#[^#]*#`, иначе, если в строке будут пустые `##` совпадения будут начинаться со второго, конечного, символа.

Чтобы решить поставленную задачу, добавте лямбду в качестве аргумента замены и передайте в него `counter`:

```py
import re
from itertools import count

line = r'#Совп. А# ... #Совп. Б# ... #Совп. В#'
counter = count(1)
line = re.sub(r'#[^#]*#', lambda x: '<{0}>{1}</{0}>'.format(str(next(counter)),x.group()), line)
print(line)
# => <1>#Совп. А#</1> ... <2>#Совп. Б#</2> ... <3>#Совп. В#</3>
```

См. [пример работы кода на Python](https://ideone.com/nT8iKQ).

В данном случае регулярное выражение находит и заменяет совпадения за один проход.

Есть ещё один вариант без дополнительного `import`, использовать вспомогательный метод, чтобы можно было передать с помощью лямбды 2 аргумена (найденный объект MatchData и счётчик):

```py
import re

line = r'#Совп. А# ... #Совп. Б# ... #Совп. В#'

def repl(x, count):
    count.i += 1
    return '<{0}>{1}</{0}>'.format(str(count.i),x.group())
 
obj = lambda:None
obj.i = 0
line = re.sub(r'#[^#]*#', lambda x: repl(x, obj), line)
print(line)
# => <1>#Совп. А#</1> ... <2>#Совп. Б#</2> ... <3>#Совп. В#</3>
```

См. [ещё один пример на Python](https://ideone.com/DgRTDW).

Comment: Интересный вариант, плюсую